# Page scales down on mobile when width is below 980px

Tags: html, css, responsive, scale, viewport

### TL;DR

When viewing my webpage on a device with a viewport thinner than 980px, everything becomes smaller than it should be, and the page itself reports the width to be stuck at 980px. In my CSS, `@media` media queries that check the page's width for values below 980px never get activated because of this. How do I prevent this?

### Repro

You'll observe this on any page, even a simple one with one line of text.

To simulate a device, I'm using my browsers built in functionality. Both Chrome and Firefox have a similar feature, in Chrome it's called "Device Toolbar" and in Firefox it's called "Responsive Design Mode", both can be found in the Developer Tools menu.

[image: Device Toolbar in Chrome] [image: Responsive Design Mode in Firefox]

In Firefox, before the issue shows itself, you also need to enable "touch simulation".

[image: Enable touch simulation in Firefox]

What you'll find is that when the viewport is wider than 980px, everything looks okay. But once you make your viewport smaller than that, everything becomes really really small:

[image: Normal scale] [image: Scaled down]

Why does this happen and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

### Why this happens

This is something mobile browsers will do automatically on pages without the `viewport` meta tag, because old websites are often not made for mobile devices and would look weird if rendered on not-so-wide screens. If your page doesn't have this tag, then mobile browsers assume it won't work well on screens with small widths, so they render the page at a minimum width of 980px to keep the original layout intact, and then scale it down to fit on your screen. This is why everything looks small.

I recommend reading this page on the MDN Web docs, it's written in a very understandable way:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

### Solution

Simply add this to your page's `<head>` element:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

`width=device-width` tells the browser to render the page using the device's resolution as the width for the viewport, no weird scaling tricks.

`initial-scale=1` sets the zoom level when you open up the page. Even though this seems redundant (the MDN page I linked above states that the default value is already 1), you'll still want to add it:

> You're using `initial-scale=1` to fight the tendency by mobile browsers to automatically zoom out when encountering web layouts, a tendency that dates back to the initial launch of the iPhone. - https://teamtreehouse.com/community/is-initialscale-not-needed